# How can I get a node by id in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I am creating a language translation using XML by id

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <word id="1">Word1_English</word>
    <word id="2">Word2_English</word>
    <word id="3">Word3_English</word>

    <word id="10001">Word1_French</word>
    <word id="10002">Word2_French</word>
    <word id="10003">Word3_French</word>

    <word id="20001">Word1_Chinese</word>
    <word id="20002">Word2_Chinese</word>
    <word id="20003">Word3_Chinese</word>
</root>
```

Code behind:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument;
FileInfo fileInfo;
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList;

string xPath = "D:\XML\LanguagePack.xml";
fileInfo = new FileInfo(xPath);
xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(fileInfo.FullName);

xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementById("10001");
return xmlNodeList[0].InnerText; //should return 'Word1_French'
```

This code doesn't work, `xmlNodeList` is null.
How can I get the content Word1_French?

Comment: What DOES it return right now, as it is?

Comment: Do you have problems with the code posted?

Comment: As GetElementById can only return a single element, you should assign the result to an XmlNode, not an XmlNodeList.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, however Cyril's answer fits my requirement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [MSDN documentation on XmlDocument.GetElementById Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx):

> The DOM implementation must have information which defines which
>   attributes are of type ID. Although attributes of type ID can be
>   defined in either XSD schemas or DTDs, this version of the product
>   only supports those defined in DTDs. **Attributes with the name "ID" are
>   not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD**. Implementations where it
>   is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to
>   return null.

In fact, you have to modify your XML file for specifying what you mean by 'ID'. If you don't want to do that, use a [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

So you need instead :

```
string filePath = "D:\\XML\\LanguagePack.xml";
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(fileInfo.FullName);

var node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='10001']");
return node.InnerText; // return 'Word1_French'
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use LINQ to XML for parsing XML. It has nice strongly typed API. Getting string word by integer id looks like (requires *System.Xml.Linq* namespace):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
string word = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                  .Where(w => (int)w.Attribute("id") == id)
                  .Select(w => (string)w)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or even less code with XPath (requires *System.Xml.XPath* namespace):

```
string word = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//word[@id='10001']");
```