# XmlDocument parse using Node ID in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlnode

How to parse through XML file using a node Id. I want to get to `<Rate>0.8988</Rate>` node of `<rate id="USDEUR">`

```
<results>
    <rate id="USDEUR">
    <Name>USD/EUR</Name>
    <Rate>0.8988</Rate>
    <Date>5/27/2016</Date>
    <Time>6:56pm</Time>
    <Ask>0.8989</Ask>
    <Bid>0.8988</Bid>
    </rate>
    <rate id="USDJPY">
    <Name>USD/JPY</Name>
    <Rate>110.1250</Rate>
    <Date>5/27/2016</Date>
    <Time>6:53pm</Time>
    <Ask>110.1500</Ask>
    <Bid>110.1250</Bid>
    </rate>
    </results>
```

This is what I am able to do so far.

```
string sitemapurl = @"http://example.com/xmlforexrates";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(sitemapurl);
XmlNodeList nodeIds = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/results/rate");
```

Right now it's getting all the `<rate>` nodes in the NodeList. I just wanted to get node on Id based for example only `<rate id="USDEUR">`

Please help me do this. Thanks

Comment: I think you got this upside down.  You have to write some code first.  If that doesn't work, then you post your code here, and ask a specific question about it to get help.

Comment: just updated my question, please remove negative marking. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786770/how-can-i-get-a-node-by-id-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

Using XPath, you can do it like this:

```
XmlNodeList nodeIds = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/results/rate[@id='USDEUR']/Rate/text()");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty trivial using LINQ to XML.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://example.com/xmlforexrates");

var rate = (decimal)doc
    .Descendants("rate")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("id") == "USDEUR")
    .Elements("Rate")
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5YfbxR) for a working demo.