# How to get value of child node of parent nodes child node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I know the question seems confusion because it is confusion to me. I thought best I show example. I have a partial xml file as shown below. I need to get the value of the `VALUE` child node of the `DIALVALUE` node but to get the correct value I need to find the correct `DIALVALUE` node by the `DIAL` id attribute. The `DIALVALUE` node is listed 71 times in the xml file and the values needed are not in order. How to accomplish this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OrderXml>
    <DialValues>
      <DialValue>
        <Dial id="11144" externalId="">
          <PlanName>pg1_CreditUnionName</PlanName>
          <DisplayName>Credit Union Name:</DisplayName>
        </Dial>
        <Value>Alexis Nab Credit Union</Value>
      </DialValue>
      <DialValue>
        <Dial id="11145" externalId="">
          <PlanName>pg1_CharterNumber</PlanName>
          <DisplayName>Charter Number:</DisplayName>
        </Dial>
        <Value>9999</Value>
      </DialValue>
      <DialValue>
        <Dial id="11146" externalId="">
          <PlanName>pg1_ContactNameFirst</PlanName>
          <DisplayName>Solution Main Contact First Name:</DisplayName>
        </Dial>
        <Value>Alexis</Value>
      </DialValue>
      <DialValue>
    </DialValues>
<OrderXml>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a node by id in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786770/how-can-i-get-a-node-by-id-in-xml)

Comment: I wish were that easy but, no it doesn't answer my question. I need to get the `<Value>` node based off of the `<Dial>` id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should give you the idea (note: include null handling, etc.).

```
var value = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants("Dial")
                .Single(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == "11145")
                .Parent
                .Descendants("Value")
                .Single().Value;
```

Comment: How would I handle the null possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); // skip the utf-16 which Net doesn't like
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            Dictionary<int, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("DialValue")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("Dial").Attribute("id"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }

}
```