# Relative xPath to get first child with given tagname c#

Tags: c#, svg, xpath

i need to create a WPF C# library to "parse" an svg file in order to find some nodes with specific Classname. Once get a reference to this node i must read some attributes.

This is the xml code:

```
    <g class="Pedale">
  <g transform=" rotate(0 711.62 520) translate(703.62, 507)" GUID="c2129b06-7ebc-c0c6-3f82-bdf605680000" Name="CA1" Symbol="pedal_contassi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="quadrato" width="15" height="10" x="0" y="0" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0" />
    <path id="freccia" d="M 1 0 L 7.5 5.5 L 14 0 Z M 14 10 L 7.5 5.5 L 1 10 Z" class="strokeFillCustomColor" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
  <g transform=" rotate(0 2571.1 520) translate(2563.1, 507)" GUID="c2129b06-39d7-df02-18d9-5ad5bcae0000" Name="CA2" Symbol="pedal_contassi" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="quadrato" width="15" height="10" x="0" y="0" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0" />
    <path id="freccia" d="M 1 0 L 7.5 5.5 L 14 0 Z M 14 10 L 7.5 5.5 L 1 10 Z" class="strokeFillCustomColor" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
  <g transform=" rotate(180 3300.4 520) translate(3292.4, 503)" GUID="c2129b06-b80b-717b-2986-469048490000" Name="AT2" Symbol="pedal_ann_sx_B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="scale(-1 1)">
      <rect id="quadrato" width="15" height="10" x="0" y="0" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0" />
      <path id="freccia" d="M 15 0 L 1 5.5 L 15 10" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
      <path id="braccetti" d="M 0 10 L 0 14 M 15 10 L 15 14" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform=" rotate(0 136.94 520) translate(128.94, 503)" GUID="c2129b06-2637-8041-a678-a5f633f70000" Name="AT1" Symbol="pedal_ann_dx_B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="scale(1 1)">
      <rect id="quadrato" width="15" height="10" x="0" y="0" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="0" />
      <path id="freccia" d="M 0 0 L 14 5.5 L 0 10" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />
      <path id="braccetti" d="M 0 10 L 0 14 M 15 10 L 15 14" class="strokeCustomColor" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

with this c# code

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(SVG_file);
XmlNodeList GList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("g");
foreach (XmlNode item in GList)
{
    if (item.Attributes["class"].Value == "Pedale")
    {
        XmlNodeList PedaleList = item.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode PedaleItem in PedaleList)
        {
            if (PedaleItem.Attributes["GUID"] != null)
            {
                XmlNode PathNode = PedaleItem.SelectSingleNode("[.//path][1]");
                string s2 = PathNode.Attributes["d"].Value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I managed to find a "g" tag with classname:"Pedale", and get all children with GUID attribute.
Now, for every "g" tagname with GUID != null i need to find the first "path" tagname in order to get its d command (so the first path with id="freccia").
I tryed to use this xPath [.//path][1] but obviously doesnt work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19786918/7081176 This comment is for how to get by Id, but I think you can pull the same off with Class.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I would like to get the first path child using xPath. So having a "g" child (of a "PedaleItem"  node) element with not null GUID, I want to use xPatht to get his first path child.

Comment: In terms of using XPath against SVG, you mainly have to understand that the SVG elements are in a namespace, the SVG namespace, and that that way, with XPath 1.0 at least, in C# you need to use an XmlNamespaceManager and a prefix (e.g. `svg`) bound to the SVG namespace, in your XPath expressions e.g. `svg:path` or `.//svg:path` and a namespace manager as the second argument to `SelectSingleNode` which binds the prefix `svg` to the SVG namespace.